# Unity ScrollView's Contents are reset when I use VerticalLayoutGroup

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview

I want to create a Level Map using a ScrollView for my game like you can see in the picture, when I add the `VerticalLayoutGroup` to the Content, all my content's children are reset, and I'm not able to change the position in the scene because the control by the `VerticalLayoutGroup`, can anymore give a solution, please?
Thx

[image]

Comment: When you add a VerticalLayoutGroup, it is expected for it to control the position of the children. If you don’t want that, why use it?

Comment: From your image I don't really understand the issue ...